# Multiplication using bitwise operators of a 2-D array with a 1-D array in C

Tags: c, for-loop, bitwise-operators

I have been trying to compute product of a 2-D array with a 1-D array using bitwise operators. For the 2-D array I have a 512 x 32 size "matrix" and the 1-D array is 32 x 1 size "vector". For my application, I want to multiply the matrix[0][0] with vector[0] and store it as one value and then matrix[0][1] with vector[1] and store that value and so on till I get the first row as 32 values.
Thereafter, I want to repeat the same operations for 512 rows so that at the end I get a 512 x 32 matrix.

I know this is not how a matrix vector multiplication is done. But, for the application I am working on, it is important that I first achieve it this way before moving ahead.

Below is the code snippet in C that I have written:

```
for(i = 0; i<512; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<32; j++)
    {
while (vector[j] != 0)              
{
    if (vector[j] & 1)               
    {
        result[i][j] += matrix[i][j];  
    }
    matrix[i][j] <<= 1;                    
                             
    vector[j] >>= 1;              
}
    }
}
```

I have declared result[i][j] of size 512 x 32. The values of "matrix" and "vector" are randomized as in I have used rand()%200 to assign random values to these.

The problem I am facing is that upon execution I am getting result[0][j] only i.e. only the first row of the result. Rest all rows it is printing as zeros (0) only.

I have trying to figure this out from a couple of days but I am stuck. Could someone please tell me where am I going wrong? And, what should I do to achieve the desired result?

P.S - Please forgive for any silly mistakes as I not fully conversant with C

Comment: The problem is that you're shifting `vector[j]` until it's 0. So after the first row, all of the `vector` elements are 0.

Comment: So, how do I overcome this problem? Because I want to iterate this process for 512 rows with the same vector.

Comment: Use a temporary variable, e.g. `int temp = vector[j];` Then use `temp` in the `while` loop. That way, only `temp` gets shifted, and `vector[j]` is not affected.

Comment: You might also want a temporary variable for `matrix[i][j]`, since the code you have is leaving a mess in `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not decrease the variable if the number is odd.
2. You need some temporary variables for calculations.
3. You do not want to `vector[j] >>= 1;` which divides it by two - you want to subtract `2`

It is much easier if you divide the problem into smaller chunks. Use functions for that.

If you multiply signed integers you need to take into the account the sign as well.

```
unsigned mult(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    while(y)
    {
        if(y & 1)
        {
            result += x;
            y--;
        }
        else
        {
            result += x << 1;
            y -= 2;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x4dG59cK4

and matrix version

```
void mult(size_t rows, size_t cols, unsigned (*x)[cols], unsigned (*y)[cols])
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            unsigned result = 0;
            unsigned y1 = y[row][col];

            while(y1)
            {
                if(y1 & 1)
                {
                    result += x[row][col];
                    y1--;
                }
                else
                {
                    result += x[row][col] << 1;
                    y1 -= 2;
                }
            }
            x[row][col] = result;
        }
    }
}
```